# create variable following the rule first number before "/"

Tags: r

I'm trying to webscrape some data. This is what I have right now:

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
theurl <- "http://www.iie.org/Research-and-Publications/Open-Doors/Data/International-Students/Enrollment-Trends/1948-2012"
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
trends <- tables[[1]][3:67,] %>% rename("International Students"=V2, "Annual % Change"=V3, "Total Enrollment"=V4, "% Int'l"=V5) %>% 
  mutate(Year = strsplit(x = as.character(V1), "/"))
```

The problem is with the variable Year. It should be 1948:2012. I could do `trends$Year=1948:2012` but I would like to learn how to do it with strsplit or something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you wanted to work with column `V1` or `Year`, but here are two ways to do it that will work with either column:

```
# Using a Regular Expression: Search for the first instance of four numeric characters 
# in a row. Keep them and throw away everything else.
trends$Year = gsub("([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", trends$Year)

# Using the substr function: Subset the first four characters in the string.
trends$Year = substr(trends$Year, 1, 4)
```